# Lactone acylation

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrophilic-substitution, acylation

Can anyone propose/draw a mechanism for Method A, below, from [this paper](http://orgsyn.org/Content/pdfs/procedures/CV4P0898.pdf)? Almost all other literature use method B and reagents such as SOCl2.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE; Unless you offer a solution to this question it will be voted down. We do not do homework but we will help you with some effort on your part. Get back to us.

Comment: This is not a homework question. I do not know where to start since there is limited literature on this.

Comment: What is the role of AlCl3? What is its reactivity? How about the lactone?

Comment: AlCl3 is a Lewis acid and activates the carbonyl oxygen.

Comment: But there is literature that I will share if you put forth your best shot.

Comment: My best shot is: the ring breaks in order to stabilize the activated oxygen. I am unsure whether it is at the 2 or 4 carbon... I am then unsure as to whether there is a hydride shift, whether an acylium or carboxylic acid group forms, how to remove the hydroxyl group, and how the benzene attacks...

Comment: Additionally I have found several papers that show that this reaction does not proceed eg https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0040403903008554?token=F148342816E4F6486CD5E79B1D727C422C4D3B931373B500965B9B20D502E5395EC2FF53B5F24E0FEFE410FF81F6F131

Comment: I find this last statement somewhat difficult to believe considering that this has been reported in Organic Syntheses, whose sole purpose is to publish procedures that are supposed to reproducible, to the extent where the published procedure should have been independently verified for being reproducible...

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: @JBG you can include all the information of yours in the comments into your question to make it more contextual rather than a mere homework question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reaction of benzene and γ-butyrolactone with AlCl<sub>3</sub> was reported by [Truce and Olson<sup>1</sup>](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01138a522?rand=smqnb1j2) in 1952. The authors found that the ratio of γ-phenylbutyric acid to α-tetralone was dependent on the  AlCl<sub>3</sub>/lactone ratio. The larger the latter ratio; the more α-tetralone. (See Table 1 from the paper). The ratio employed in the *Organic Syntheses* preparation is 3.7. Table 2 from Truce's paper provides an explanation for the role of excess AlCl<sub>3</sub> but it doesn't explain the alkylation of benzene.
The lactone-AlCl<sub>3</sub> complex **1** can act as an electrophile aromatic alkylation (**1**-->**2**-->**3**). Subsequent intramolecular acylation of **4** leads to α-tetralone **6**. Bear in mind that γ-butyrolactone reacts with HBr to form γ-bromobutyric acid.

[image]

1) [W. E. Truce and C. E. Olson, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1952**, *74*, 4721.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01138a522?rand=smqnb1j2)